# Macbook can't find SSD

Tags: macos, catalina

I have a Macbook Air 2014. Unfortunately, after updating macOS 10.15.5 there was a bug showing that "need to restart" after two restarts then the "Question Mark Folder" appeared. During this pandemic situation, no Apple store nearby is open for checkup. Any help?

[image: Recovery]

Comment: Run Apple Diagnostics (hold D at restart) and see what it says. It could very well just be a hardware failure that *coincidentally* happened during the update. If it was a soft (disk) error you would see the internal SSD in Disk Utility. But you don't leading me to believe it is a hardware issue, rather than software.

Comment: Apple Stores were suppose to open last week. unless you're in one of the 4 states that Apple decided to shut them down again? Or a country that is still waiting to reopen.

Comment: Use the text based `diskutil` instead.  Issue the command in Terminal `diskutil list` and post your output to imgur or pastebin (or similar) as it will be lengthy.  Then we can figure out what happened.

Comment: That's a very old Recovery partition - look at the dots, top left. Though that shouldn't stop it seeing the disk, it will prevent it from reading it. Try Internet Recovery, Cmd/Opt/R at boot, which will at least load a modern Recovery.

Comment: @Allan there just one disk0 and thats only 1gb or so and other is like few megs.

Comment: @jmh am not at US

Comment: Are you booting Internet Recovery?  `Cmd-Opt-R` ?

Comment: @Allan yes, am in internet recovery mode